# Why does removeOnGlobalLayoutListener throw a NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: android

I have some code that compiles successfully using `ViewTreeObserver#removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)` and when it runs, this method throws `NoSuchMethodError`.  Why?

Comment: I know the solution, I was just posting in the popular and vibrant question-and-answer format :)

Comment: I'm assuming you were just trying to get a few upvotes, but you can redeem yourself at least giving @azertiti the right answer :)

Comment: @Rigotti Actually I was trying to point out that there are two methods in Android with the same function and almost the same name, because that seemed like a useful thing to know if you were trying to use one and for some reason it failed to work.  But thanks for your cynical interpretation of my motives!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467

Answer (score 150, accepted):

There are *two* methods in `ViewTreeObserver` with almost the same name.

[`removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeOnGlobalLayoutListener%28android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener%29)

(**on** then **global**) is a method that was added in API 16.  It replaces

[`removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener victim)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeGlobalOnLayoutListener%28android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener%29)

(**global** then **on**) which has existed since API 1, but which is now deprecated.

Both methods can appear present at compile-time (if you're building against Jellybean or higher) but the newer one will fail on pre-Jellybean devices.

This code thwarts the error:

```
try {
    thing.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(victim);
} catch (NoSuchMethodError x) {
    thing.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(victim);
}
```

So does this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    thing.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(victim);
} else {
    thing.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(victim);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your problem and solution. I tried your code and still facing issue. Would you look at my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285540/stop-listening-for-more-listener-events?

Comment: Wow, it's like Google is trying to troll developers. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: Ha, I know what you mean! I think it's for consistency with `ViewTreeObserver#addOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)` and someone made a mistake in Android 1.5, and nobody bothered to fix it till Android 4 ....

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are talking about removeOnGlobalLayoutListener from ViewTreeObserver class. This method was added in API level 16. My best guess is that you try to use it on a device running an old version of Android that's why it can't be found.

Comment: I know, I just found that out and thought it would be worth telling everyone about `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(...)` (deprecated, API 1) :)

Answer (score 3):

I have working code

```
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
    } else {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }
}
```