# Stop listening for more listener events

Tags: android, listener, event-listener

I listen to `onGlobalLayoutListener` as shown in below code. I want to listen it only once.
Once `onGlobalLayout()` is called I want to stop listening to it.

I tried using `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener()` method but that gives warning that **call required API level 16 (current min is 14)**.

I also tried using `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener`. But it is deprecated.

**Code :**

```
searchWebView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                        new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        // Do something
        // Remove listener
    }
});
```

How to remove `onGlobalLayoutListener`?

**Edit :**

[image]

Comment: Read this Thread [ViewTreeObserver]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162821/why-does-removeongloballayoutlistener-throw-a-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: @strike That gives same error. See my edited question has image. First one is said to be deprecated and hence crosses line over it. Second is added in level 16 and mine is 14.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` using the following code. There will still be a `strikethrough` on `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()`, which has been deprecated. But, the lint  warning will be taken care of by using the annotations.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
searchWebView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
                searchWebView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                searchWebView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you know why `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()` method has still has a black line over it? Will not it cause problem when this method stops working.i.e. android stops supporting it.?

Comment: @Akash This is eclipse' way of showing that a deprecated method is being used in code. For all intensive purposes, using a deprecated method in this manner is correct. `Will not it cause problem when this method stops working.i.e. android stops supporting it.?`. No. The method call will happen for the API version that supports it. And android does not take away functionality from older APIs. It add new(and possibly better) features in new API version. Older APIs stay the same. If anything, they get better with all the `compat libraries` that android releases.

Comment: Eggcorn! http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/32/intensive-purposes/

(sorry, couldn't resist!)

Comment: @RussWheeler `For all INTENTS AND purposes`.. this.. makes.. so.. much.. more.. sense! Thanks man, I wasn't aware of eggcorns in general :)

Comment: No worries @Vikram. Listen out for more eggcorns and life will be much funnier :)